# disable console-kit logging

Tags: logs, consolekit

My X login manager (slim) has brought with it a dependency on a package `consolekit` I don't know what `consolekit` is good for, other login managers such as `wdm` do not need it.

But anyway, the problem I am having is that `consolekit` is logging lots of garbage in `/var/log/ConsoleKit/history`. I am not interested in those logs. Is it possible to disable logging?

I have tried removing the log file and creating a symlink to `/dev/null`

```
ln -s /dev/null /var/log/ConsoleKit/history
```

But that does not work, because `consolekit` now complains that there are too many levels of symbolic links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConsoleKit doesn't accept symbolic links for the log file as you mentioned in your question.

But you can trick consolekit a bit, when you create a null device instead of a normal log file. First remove the history file:

```
rm /var/log/ConsoleKit/history
```

And then use this command:

```
mknod /var/log/ConsoleKit/history c 1 3
```

That creates a null device (`c`: character special, `1`: major number and `3` minor number).

Now, everthing that is logged in this file is deleted and needs no space on the filesystem.

Comment: so basically, this will create a second `/dev/null` file, named `/var/log/ConsoleKit/history` ? I have `/var` partition mounted with `nodev` option, will this still work?

Comment: @MartinVegter This will end in a `Permissin denied` when writing to this device. But, there is stil another option: a bind mount. Before creating the null device, run this command: `mount --bind $(mktemp -d) /var/log/ConsoleKit/`. Then create the device as in my answer. You can test with `echo "blah" >/var/log/ConsoleKit/history` which should not fail in a permissin error.

Answer (score 1):

From [FreeDesktop.Org](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ConsoleKit/)

> ConsoleKit is a framework for defining and tracking users, login
>   sessions, and seats.

Also note:

> ConsoleKit is currently not actively maintained. The focus has shifted
>   to the built-in seat/user/session management of Software/systemd
>   called systemd-logind!

**Documentation**

No longer maintained but [available here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html)

To disable it, see:
[console-kit-daemon Hogging CPU and RAM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68597/console-kit-daemon-hogging-cpu-and-ram) or
[Gentoo Wiki: Consolekit](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/ConsoleKit)

Answer (score 0):

Make the log file immutable as root.

```
sudo echo "" > /var/log/ConsoleKit/history/<log_filename>
sudo chattr +i /var/log/ConsoleKit/history/<log_filename>
```